# Await ignorado em método assíncrono c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone, async, asynctask, signalr

Preciso usar o retorno de um método assíncrono para validação porém mesmo com o uso do "await" o método segue sendo executado antes que eu receba o retorno da função.

```
    var teste = await new VendaService().EnviarVendaParaServicoCentral(new List<ItemVenda>(), new Venda());
    if (teste)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("feito");
    }
```

Método assíncrono com outras chamadas assíncronas:

```
public async Task<bool> EnviarVendaParaServicoCentral(List<ItemVenda> itensVenda, Venda venda)
{
    try
    {
        await this._conHelper._connection.Start();
        this._vendaEfetuada = false;
        await this._conHelper._hubProxy.Invoke("RealizarVenda", itensVenda, venda);
        this._conHelper._hubProxy.On<bool>("RetornoDaVenda", (retornoServicoCentral) =>
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                this._vendaEfetuada = retornoServicoCentral;
            })
        );

        return this._vendaEfetuada;                
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @JéfersonBueno esse é o problema, não sei o que esta errado, ele não espera com o uso do await... o por que é que é a dúvida.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Até onde sei, o await é usado para forçar a espera.

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o "método segue sendo executado antes que eu receba o retorno da função"? O valor da variável `teste` só existe depois que a função retorna (na verdade, quando a sua continuação é chamada, depois da mudança que o compilador faz pelo await), então a continuação do método (`if (teste) ...`) só é executado depois que a sua função retorna. Não é o caso? Se a linha `if (teste)...` está sendo executada, então a variável `teste` tem um valor, que foi produzido pelo método que foi *awaited*.

Comment: @JéfersonBueno Isso, não é o caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para métodos assíncronos que retornam `Task<object>` no seu caso `Task<bool>`, você tem que acessar a propriedade "Result"
Exemplo:
Método

```
public static async Task<int> test()
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {   Console.WriteLine("do stuff"); });
        await t;
        return 10;
    }
```

Chamada

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{

    Task<int> test1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => test());
    System.Console.WriteLine(test1.Result); // block and wait for the result
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599074/how-do-you-get-the-return-value-of-an-async-method

O que você pode fazer também é definir um método de call back para o seu método.

```
private async void Search()
{
    await Search(SearchCompleted);//<--pass the callback method here
}

private async Task Search(Action<string> callback)
{
    //Here you're done with the file so invoke the callback that's it
    callback(file);//pass which file is finished 
}

private void SearchCompleted(string file)
{
    //this method will be called whenever a file is processed
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003594/fire-callback-after-async-task-method